# CRUD in jquery (direct edit and update a data)

Tags: jquery

I've done the *create* function (demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UD44t/)
),  but now having some trouble implementing the *edit* part. The edit code is working alone perfectly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kidino/6dj9n/3/), just tht I don't know how to combine them to work together..

current code :
**html**

```
<ul style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0">
                    <li style="list-style:none" id="active" ><a href="#" >Personal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="add">Add</a></li>
                </ul>   

                    <input type="text" name="task-group" style="display:none">
```

**jquery**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=task-group]").hide();

    var addBtn = $("#add");
    var inputBar = $("input[name=task-group]");

    $(addBtn).click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(inputBar).show().focus();
        $(inputBar).val('');
    }); 


$(inputBar).blur(function(){
        if($(inputBar).val() !== ""){
        var text = $(this).val();
        $(addBtn).show();
        $(inputBar).hide();

        $('#active').append("<li id='active'><a href='#'>" + text + "</a></li>");


        } // if close 
        else {
            $(addBtn).show();
            $(inputBar).hide();
        }
    }); 

    $(inputBar).keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).blur();
    }
    });


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UD44t/1/)

Change your html as:

```
<ul class="container" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0">
       <li style="list-style:none" class="item" id="active" ><a href="#" >Personal</a></li>

</ul>  
<br/> 
<a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
<input type="text" name="task-group" style="display:none"/>
```

Change your javascript as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=task-group]").hide();

    var addBtn = $("#add");
    var inputBar = $("input[name=task-group]");
    var beforeItems = $('li.item');

    $(addBtn).click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(inputBar).show().focus();
        $(inputBar).val('');
    });


    $(inputBar).blur(function () {
        if ($(inputBar).val() !== "") {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $(addBtn).show();
            $(inputBar).hide();

            $('ul.container').append("<li class='item' ><a href='#'>" + text + "</a></li>");
            items = $('li.item');
            items.on('click', itemClick);
        } // if close 
        else {
            $(addBtn).show();
            $(inputBar).hide();
        }
    });

    $(inputBar).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });

    var itemClick = function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.target).closest('li.item');
        var txt = $this.find('a').text();

        var activeInput = $("<input type='text'/>").val(txt);
        $this.html('');

        activeInput.appendTo($this).focus();
        activeInput.on('blur', activeInputBlur);
    };

    var activeInputBlur = function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.target);
        var v = $this.val();
        if (v.trim() == "") {
            alert('Field cannot be empty');
            $this.focus();
        } else {
            var $a = $("<a href='#'>" + v + "</a>");
            $this.parent().append($a);
            $this.remove();
        }
    };

    beforeItems.on('click', itemClick);
});
```

Comment: got bug.. u try to click on the 1st item.. after u added others, click again.. the field will clear everything..

Comment: what is the problem? at least let me know :)

Comment: The problem was, `$(e.target)` targets `a` because `li` contains `a`. In order to obtain `li` item, I tried `$(e.target).closest('li.item')` to catch `li`.

Comment: can u bind the keydown function for the edit as well? where to add them? i hv that code written for when the user press enter key when they try to create a new tab..

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/UD44t/2/ ; some changes are done and in itemClick function keydown method added.